# How do I get a Dell Truemobile 1150 working?

Tags: 11.10, wireless

In case you can not tell I am very new to ubuntu and need assistance.  I have a Dell Truemobile 1150 with the lucent chipset.

I need help installing the hermies drivers on my dell inspiron 1100 laptop please.  I need as much help as I can get because I am fairly new and want to get this card working right. Thanks in advavance

DOES ANYONE KNOW AYTHING THAT CAN HELP ME PLEASE?!?!?!?!?  I AM DOWN TO ONLY THIS CARD.

Answer (score 0):

See http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Dell_TrueMobile_1150_PC_Card.  Try the orinoco driver.